# Suitescript loading dropdown in client script

Tags: client, netsuite, suitescript2.0

and thanks, I am creating a Suitelet in SS2, I need to filter across three selects on the client side. I was able to load the initial drop-down using 'insertSelectOption' but I cannot select any item. When I choose one it goes back to the blank option. I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. The entire list is loading in the select fine. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only change the dependent dropdown lists via custom code-added form fields. I'm sure it would help if you were to post your code that you're trying to implement.

Comment: I am just putting together the plan itself and writing a proof of concept. Basically it is three dropdowns each feeding the next. Select from one and it loads two, the two loads three. I want to use the click event from each dropdown to trigger the next one to load. You mentioned custom code added form fields can you expand on that? thanks

Comment: Addendum, in the initial code, the one that I used to get the problem. Was loading the first dropdown on the client side, using insertSelectOption. If that helps. Thanks again for any help

Comment: Every field on a Suitelet is a custom field. I misread this to be on another record. Anyway, what you want to do is create a client script that has the FieldChange trigger. When your first field value is selected, create a POST back to the same page suitelet to get the second set of filtered data. Then do the same for when the second field is selected. Are you using SS1.0 or SS2.x?

Comment: Thanks I was going to do this front end only with no posts, I was already aware of the possibility of posting. That is actually something I am helping the client get away from. I have run across some ideas to help me do that. thanks again.